# How can i skip bad sector on my hard Drive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk, ram, fdisk

I have one external hard drive which i plug to my linux machine.
It causes read and write operation problems.

1. When i check it with `fdisk -l` it wait for information to display for while.
   After few minute it got display.
2. i had use `badblocks` command for checking bad sector on disk.
   After around 1:30 min it gives total 1040+ bad sector location.

So is there any way to skip this location and use remaining memory ??? Or fixing this problem. whether i need to change it.

Comment: have you formatted it once??

Comment: @Sushantp606 no not at all.

Comment: Is that 1 minute 30 seconds, or 1 hour, 30 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

Bad Sectors on hard drive can not be recovered or ignored. i have seen such questions So please have a look at these -

[Question 1](https://askubuntu.com/q/62859/192102)

[Question 2](https://askubuntu.com/q/125679/192102)

[Question 3](https://askubuntu.com/q/346401/192102)

The Only thing you can do is **Get a new Hard Drive** as in future fortunately you may loose your important data saved in that.

Precautions are better than Cure.

Comment: thanks, when i recover data from my hard drive at specific location it got leg or hang and process remain same for long time. secondly i attached it with linux machine and try to access but fail..

Answer (score 1):

Run `badblocks -nv /dev/sdx`. Replace `dev/sdx` with the drive you want to check (with the drive unmounted). This makes a read-write test on the drive and check the SMART stats after. `-nv` specifies that the test is non-destructive (will not damage your data) and will give you status.

If there are plenty of reallocated sectors, then you need to replace the drive asap.  If not, and the pending count is zero, then the drive should be fine.

Adding `-c 1024` to badblocks makes it go significantly faster too.

Comment: the command `badblocks -n` doesn't do anything. it just displays a list of other commands